# Get heart rate information from Apple watch to paired iPhone

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

I want to get user's heart rate information from watch and store it in paired iPhone's health app. I know we can store heart rate information through health kit but can we pass heart rate data from watch to paired iPhone?

Comment: Your WatchKit app does not have access to the heart rate sensor.  The only way to access the heart rate data is via healthkit (which will not be close to real-time btw).

Comment: And where does the healthkit get this information?

Comment: It is synced from the paired Watch every so often.

Comment: So it won't be real time and instead recorded whenever user check his/her heart rate info on the watch. Right?

Comment: It certainly won't be real time.  The conditions for when the data is recorded and synced over are less clear.

Comment: I was going through following link: http://www.quora.com/Apple-Watch-in-2015/In-what-form-does-Apple-Watch-return-heart-rate-data-to-the-apps-What-is-the-frequency-and-precision-of-data-points

Comment: Where the person says "Frequency of writes from the Watch to Health app will depend on which mode a user has selected. Active tracking is constant, tracking every pulse. Other tracking records as often as once every 10 minutes." I was wondering how did he get that information? Any Idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.** There is no open API for developers for getting data from heart-rate sensor. Apple uses their private methods for doing this.

**2.** Your idea about getting this data already from HealthKit is not good:

- Information can be outdated.
- As I know, user can select if he wants to track his heart rate or
  not. And you have no ability to check if this information is
  tracked.

So, currently, there is no suitable options for making heart tracking app.

---

**UPDATE (2015-06-09)**

On the WWDC15 Apple announced watchOS 2.

In this update there will be realtime access to the heart rate sensor and other sensors!
More info is here: https://developer.apple.com/watchos/pre-release/

Comment: do we have access to heart rate sensor in apple watch?